# How to prompt Safari to save website's username and password to keychain?

Tags: safari, keychain

Given the site: https://ritx-fl-sales.bswa.net, username and password: how do I prompt Safari to save the username and password to the keychain, so that it is available next time I need to logon to the website?

I have logged into the site 3 times today, however, Safari did not prompt to save credentials

Answer (score 2):

Check in the preferences if you denied saving passwords in the past for the website. Go to Safari Preferences (`CMD` + `,`), passwords tab. Unlock it and sort the list by passwords column. If the site shows "Never Saved", site will not prompt for saving credentials. One can also search for the site using the search bar in this password window.

Otherwise, manually adding the credentials is the way to go. In the same place, use add button and fill in the site URL and the password. Even then, some sites may **not** support autofill partially or even fully. It's upto the web developer. See if this site works that way or not after manual addition.

> Safari may be unable to tell which fields are for username and password, credit card number and expiry date, and so forth.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/safari/ibrw1100/12.0/mac/10.14

Comment: Please elaborate for the community the steps or references to steps for the two good suggestions?

Comment: It's worth noting that some webpages just won't play ball with Keychain. The web interface for my Netgear wifi router resolutely refuses even when I manually create a correct Keychain entry.

Comment: Yes some websites don't allow autofill and it's  annoying . I hope my last para indicates this. @David

Comment: Not quite, IMO. The last paragraph only addresses confusion about what information goes in what field, not the broader "I won't interface at all" response.

Comment: @David how's this now?

Comment: Yep, that covers it. Thanks for the edit.